# Use another variable to color-code single quiver arrows

Tags: matlab, vector, colors, field

how would one go about to get and use a color-coding from a variable to color a single quiver3 line?

I append a picture where i made a scatter plot in variable z that i would like the blue line emanating from there to be the same color. Is there a possibility?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You can use [a loop](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/151954) or if you want to colour them based on vector magnitude then you could use [quiverc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc) from the FEX. Might be worth taking a look inside `quiverc` anyways

Comment: i looked ad quiverc but it is only 2D. that is why i am asking here.

Comment: But did you look inside `quiverc` at the actual code to see how it works?

Comment: i am not that good in programming and it looks quite confusing to me what exactly i need to change to make it available for 3D, but i guess i have no other option at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not with standard `quiver`. There's a file available on the File Exchange called [quiverc](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc), which uses the magnitude of the vector as the line color.

It's also not too hard to roll your own:

```
function colQuiver(xyz, uvw, cdata)

    %// this makes it suitable for both 2D and 3D
    xyz = num2cell(xyz);
    uvw = num2cell(uvw);   

    for ii = 1:size(xyz,1)

        L = cellfun(@(x,y) [0;x] + [y;y], ...
            uvw(ii,:), xyz(ii,:),...
            'Uniformoutput', false);
        L = line(L{:});
        set(L, 'color', cdata(ii,:));

    end

end
```

Note that I didn't test this at all, there's no error checking, and you might want to allow other ways of specifying the color than just RGB values (use a `LineSpec`, via current colormap, ...)...But the essence it there ^_^

Comment: Hi, i have tried it but couldn't get the colouring to work since at leafs three number values are needed for RGB. I gave up on trying to make it work and just make the plots i need like upstairs.
Thank your or your time anyways.

Comment: @IceQueeny: ...so you are using colors from the current colormap?

Comment: I just don't do what i intended to do. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering for colored arrows:
[QuiverS](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24482-quivers) and [Uquiver](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24080-uquiver) and [Streakarrow3d](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23263-streakarrow3d). But none of them does what i want. They all have the arrows the same length and color coded, however i'd rather have them different lengths and color coded with yet another variable.